# How to display a form in PHP?

Tags: php, forms, echo

I need to display a form through PHP, but I don't want to use the "echo" function or the "print" method. This is a user registration form. But I am having trouble using the two mentioned methods.
My code:

```
<?Php
if(!isset($_SESSION['userid'])){
<form> 
 //My form here... 
</form>
exit;
}else{
<form> 
 //My other form here... 
</form>
?>
```

Comment: Php closing tag is `?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```php
<?php if (!isset($_SESSION['userid'])) { ?>
<form>
...
</form>
<?php } else { ?>
<form>
...
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

...or with alternative syntax for control structures:

```php
<?php if (!isset($_SESSION['userid'])): ?>
<form>
...
</form>
<?php else: ?>
<form>
...
</form>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!